# Waiting page on Blogger with Javascript

Tags: javascript, blogger, countdowntimer, blogger-dynamic-views

i'd like to install a waiting page for each click,  on a link,  in an article on my blogger

(i.e,  in an article, i putted a link, if you click there,  you'll be redirected in a waiting page first, we're there is a countdown Timer,  then the link will open after the countdown in this waiting page)

But i've a problem now, i've a waiting page for every click on my blog...even on facebook link,  category link...item link....
Or i juste want it for all link in each article...but anyelse where...
What i've to do? Thank you for your help

To do it,  i've seen this script...

1.They told me to create a new page on blogger, and to copy it (in html editing mode)....and to copy the url after

```html
<div class="post-body entry-content" id="post-body-6502615055052287195">
<div dir="rtl" style="text-align: right;" trbidi="on">
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" trbidi="on">
<style type="text/css">
a#reload {display: none;}
#redirection {    background: #344275;
    padding: 14px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<!-- ads -->
<!-- page de telechargement -->

<br />
<!-- ads1 -->
<!-- page de telechargement 1 -->

<br />
<!--text -->

<!-- ads2 -->
<!-- page de telechargement 2 -->

<br />
<!-- ads3 -->

<br />
<div id="redirection">
<div style="text-align: center;">
Wait a few seconds <span id="countdown"> 15 </span> 
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size: 45px;"></i>
  <a href="https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=4500602314747018461#" id="reload">
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
<br />
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tr-caption-container" style="background-color: white; font-family: &quot;times new roman&quot;; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
 <tbody>
<tr>
   <td style="text-align: center;"><div style="margin: 0px;">
<a href="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OMrIXfuEJIk/W8C7Q1Zw-kI/AAAAAAAAAdw/0Tt3l01G-HMWPNJbHhrXNlSCDlKmq8c9ACLcBGAs/s1600/240_f_30149499_4ch2civydq7ijghtg276rp0g11crqxnk.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
     <img border="0" data-original-height="240" data-original-width="640" height="75" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OMrIXfuEJIk/W8C7Q1Zw-kI/AAAAAAAAAdw/0Tt3l01G-HMWPNJbHhrXNlSCDlKmq8c9ACLcBGAs/s200/240_f_30149499_4ch2civydq7ijghtg276rp0g11crqxnk.jpg" style="cursor: move;" width="200" />
    </a>
    </div>
</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td class="tr-caption" style="font-size: 12.8px;"><div style="margin: 0px;">
<div style="font-size: 12.8px;">
<b><u><span style="color: #3d85c6; font-size: large;">ici</span></u></b></div>
</div>
</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
//add Font Awesome
      var cb = function() {
        var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
        l.href = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css';
        var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
      };
      var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
          webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
      if (raf) raf(cb);
      else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
//]]></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds;
  var temp;
function removem1() {
    var xkl = getQueryVariable("url");
    var nkl=xkl.replace("&m=1", "");
document.getElementById("reload").innerHTML=nkl;
}
removem1();
document.getElementById('reload').href=window.location.href;
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("?&&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=_");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

  function countdown() {
    seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
    seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10);

    if (seconds == 0) {
      temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
      parent.location.replace(document.getElementById("reload").innerHTML)
           return;
    }
    seconds--;
    temp = document.getElementById('countdown');
    temp.innerHTML = seconds;
    timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(countdown, 1500);
  } 
setTimeout(function(){ countdown(); }, 5000);
</script>


</div>
</div>
```

2.Then...to excecute it...i've to copy a script in the end of the body of my theme too...this script:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
var allahref=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var c=0;c<allahref.length;c++)
{
if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.(paste here your URL)" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="web.facebook.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.youtube.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="play.google.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="plus.google.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.linkedin.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.instagram.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="twitter.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="1.bp.blogspot.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="2.bp.blogspot.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="3.bp.blogspot.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="4.bp.blogspot.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.blogger.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.instagram.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
{
allahref[c].href="(paste here the URL of the page)?&&url=_"+allahref[c].href;
}
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in step 2.

I really don't understand if you want just the same url to display the waiting page or if you want more than one... Anyway, that script has a bunch of domain urls already set so you can try to comment the script like this (*so that you can easily revert it or uncomment if you want to use any of them*):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
var allahref=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var c=0;c<allahref.length;c++)
{
if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.(paste here your URL)" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="web.facebook.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.youtube.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="play.google.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="plus.google.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.linkedin.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.instagram.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="twitter.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="1.bp.blogspot.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="2.bp.blogspot.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="3.bp.blogspot.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="4.bp.blogspot.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.blogger.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
//if(allahref[c].hostname!="www.instagram.com" && allahref[c].hostname!="")
{
allahref[c].href="(paste here the URL of the page)?&&url=_"+allahref[c].href;
}
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Remember to paste your URLs where it says in the script. From what I can see, you must write a new line for every domain URL. Instagram is repeated in two lines but I think it's a mistake.
1, 2, 3 and 4.bp.blogspot are the domain urls from images from Blogger and the plus.google is obsolete as Google Plus is dead now.

What the commented script above does is only make it work your chosen url link. If it works like you want, then for every link you want o apply that waiting page you must write that url into a new line.

Mind you that I have not tested this yet as I'm nowhere near my home computer to test it myself on Blogger.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explaination is very useful for me :) i'll try it